# how to unit test select from "@angular-redux/store" in angular 10?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular10

I am having a reducer defined as :

```
export const dummy_reducer = (state: any = INITIAL_STATE, action: any): any => {


  const actionOptions = (actionType) => ({
    GET_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS: () => {
      return tassign(state, {
        emp_name: action.payload.emp_name
      });
    },
```

and I am using it in my component.ts as follows:

```
 @select(["dummy_reducer", "emp_name"])
  emp_name$: Observable<any>;
```

Also when the component is getting initialised ,I am using the emp_name$ to subscribe like below:

ngOnInit() {
this.emp_name$.subscribe((details) => {
.........
}
});
}

Now my question is how can i write unit test for this particular component,
when i am running ng test,I am getting error as :

```
 Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined ...
```

at this ngOnInIt().
Any suggestion on how to fix it??.
Please let me know how can i write a successful spec file for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `NgReduxTestingModule`, then having `@select('loading') loading$: Observable<boolean>` inside the component we can test it:

```
const stub = MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub('loading');
stub.next(false);
stub.next(true);
stub.complete();

component.loading$
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(
    actualSequence => expect(actualSequence).toEqual([ false, true ]),
    null,
    done);
```

You can even mock the data inside `beforeEach` function so it will be available for all tests :)

Code refence taken from [here](https://github.com/angular-redux/example-app/blob/master/src/app/elephants/page.spec.ts) check it for more tests examples